# Dynamic array access violation error

Tags: pascal

```
program LengthOfArray;
uses sysutils;

procedure Main();
var myArray: array of String;
begin
    myArray[0] := 'hi';
    myArray[1] := 'bye';
    myArray[2] := 'hello';

    WriteLn('array is: ', Length(myArray));

end;

begin
    Main();
end.
```

When I run this, it gives me an error like this:

> > An unhandled exception occurred at $0040210C :
> >     EAccessViolation : Access violation
> >       $0040210C
> >       $00401540
> >       $004015ED

When compiling, it gave me a message Warning: Local variable "myArray" does not seem to be initialized... but I don't understand because I assigned 3 values to my array already. Isn't that initialized?

Comment: When compiling, it gave me a message Warning: Local variable "myArray" does not seem to be initialized... but I dont understand because I assigned 3 values to my array already isnt that initialized?

Comment: Please use the "edit" button under the tag of your question when you want to correct or add info to your question. The warning and error are related to your array, which is a *dynamic arra*, it has no elements to begin with. You must set its length, before assigning values to the elements. See `SetLength()` in docs.

Comment: Are you compiling this with FreePascal?

Comment: Dynamic arrays do not magically add values. They need to be initialized or resized using `SetLength` before use. The proper code would be `SetLength(myArray, 3); myArray[0] := 'hi';`.

Comment: What you think is right for static arrays that have a known number of elements. But you are using a *dynamic array*, and these don't have any elements unless you *initialize their length* using `SetLength`, e.g. `SetLength(myArray, 3);` After that, `myArray` has 3 elements, and you can access them as `myArray[0]`up to `myArray[2]`. If you need more elements, you can apply `SetLength`again, to add more elements, e.g. `SetLength(myArray, 20);`. That will preserve the elements already in the array.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Adding the SetLength(); code fixed the issue.